# Where is the best place to build a castle

Tags: magic

I have no idea where to put my castle Should a castle be at the Center of the capital, to the rear, on a plateau ect... from a military and economic perspective where should a castle be placed within a capital

Comment: If you already have a capital city then it is a few centuries too late to build a castle. (Unless it is a pleasure castle; in this case, you want to build it a few miles outside the city -- see Versailles, Sans-Souci, Schoenbrunn.) What you probably want to do is to fortify the city -- walls with towers and gates, or a ring of forts, depending on the historical era. In the rare occasions where militarily semi-functional fortifications were built inside existing capitals (e.g., Hradčany in Prague) they were built on defendable hills, mimicking the acropoleis or citadels of ancient city-states.

Comment: I'm not sure this can be answered without some details about the capital itself. Is it small? Large? Is it located on a hill? On a river? Surrounded by ocean on three sides? I presume from the "magic" tag that you're asking about a world in which magic is commonplace, which may also affect the answer depending on how your magic system works.

Comment: I think this is a question for history.se and not worldbuilding

Comment: @AlexP: Versailles &c are not castles, they're palaces.  You might compare e.g. Windsor Castle https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windsor_Castle (particularly the historic versions) or the Tower of London https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tower_of_London  to Buckingham Palace: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buckingham_Palace

Comment: @jamesqf: Hence "pleasure castle". We have quite a lot of those in Europe, built in the 18th and 19th centuries. If it looks like the Disney castle, then it never had any military function and it is basically a vacation home. (Windsor Castle is mostly a 19th century state palace, incorporating some small parts of a very much smaller 11th century castle.)

Comment: Young world building friend, do whatever you want. If you keep at it, you will learn so much more. But for now, what's important is fun. Do whatever you like. Have a dragon living in that castle. If I remember correctly, the most successful world builder today is a woman called j Rowling. She knows absolutely nothing about knights, castles, the middle ages or anything else people here obsess about. She knows how to spark interest in people, something more important. Don't worry about such things, use your imagination and do whatever you please

Comment: @AlexP: True, but you're reversing causality.  Newschwanstein and similar "castles" were built long before Disney.  (Indeed, I suspect Disney of plagarism there :-))  But there are certainly many examples of castles built for military purposes, and not much modified since.  A couple of my personal favorites: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Olavinlinna https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chillon_Castle (For the OP, note the use of lakes as a defensive feature.)

Answer (score 4):

The castle was there first.

Castles go on the most defensible terrain, usually meaning the high ground in the area. Everyone would live within the walls, and farmers would go out during the day to farm the surrounding fields, etc. and bring any food collected back inside for safety.

As the population grew over the centuries, cheaper structures would be built outside the walls to add housing, with folks living there only going inside to conduct business or when under siege. These outbuildings gradually became more permanent and eventually formed a city that surrounded the castle, with another wall around them in recognition that they won't all fit inside the castle anymore.

Depending on geography and topography, the city may have spread more in one direction than another. Depending on when your story is set and whether there has been a period of lasting peace, the city may have continued to expand beyond the city wall, with the area inside the wall referred to as the "Old City". You can see this all over Europe, though typically once this happens the old wall isn't maintained anymore and may have been removed to make travel easier, with only the castle remaining.

Comment: As far as I know, peasants didn't live in castles but only took refuge in them when armies invaded.  Peasants lived in separate houses outside the castle walls.

Comment: @M.A.Golding Hovels, they are called. About 1 notch above pigsty.